# Java GUI Button actionPerformed

Tags: java, user-interface

i'm making a simple application that can print an average of 4 numbers. And i applied Java GUI on it.[image]

But the Nganuin! and exit button doesn't work with my code.
Here's my attempt:

```
  private void butNganuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       Double num2, num3, num4, num1, hasil;
       num1 = Double.parseDouble(l1.getText());
       num2= Double.parseDouble(l2.getText());
       num3= Double.parseDouble(l3.getText());
       num4= Double.parseDouble(l4.getText());

       hasil= (num1+num2+num3+num4)/4;

       jLabel5.setText(String.valueOf(hasil));
    }                                        

    private void exitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

What did i do wrong.

Comment: where do you bind actions with buttons?

Comment: Can you post the code where you bind butNganuActionPerformed() to the click event of the button?

Comment: `butNganu.setText("Nganuin!");
        butNganu.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                butNganuActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to replace your methods with something such as this:

```
butNganu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Double num2, num3, num4, num1, hasil;
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(l1.getText());
        num2= Double.parseDouble(l2.getText());
        num3= Double.parseDouble(l3.getText());
        num4= Double.parseDouble(l4.getText());

        hasil= (num1+num2+num3+num4)/4;

        jLabel5.setText(String.valueOf(hasil));                                                 
    }
});
```

This will bind the button to the event handler.

Comment: i think i did bind the button as i posted at the comment...
i'll try your advice

Comment: @HaydarAlaidrus: if that is how you did it, it should work.

Comment: you mean my first code or your advice? im not on my laptop now @npinti

Comment: @HaydarAlaidrus: If I am understanding your code, what you did and I are the same.